# C# SQLite – Best way to get values from single row

Tags: c#, sqlite

What’s the best way to get the column data from a single row? 
For example; I run a query, but I know that it will only give me 1 row back. 
From that I want to get the column details. At the moment I’m putting ToList and then doing a foreach. But this seams excessive when there’s only 1 row. How do I get to “items” without the foreach?

```
class inProgress
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool whatIsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime whatTime { get; set; }
}
```

Code to get the values out:

```
using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
 {
     var row = conn.Table<inProgress>().Where(v => v.ID.Equals(1)).ToList();
     foreach (var items in row)
     {
       isActive = items.Active;
       whatIsActive = items.whatIsActive;
       time = items.whatTime;
     }
 }
```

I know I'll only get 1 row, so do i have to run through the foreach??

**Second part.**

I prefer to user the SQL commands as strings (like below), but this seems only good in returning a single value. Again, how would I get a single row and access all the values in it, or if it returned multiple rows?

```
using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
{
   var sqlQuery = conn.CreateCommand("select * from inProgress where ID = ?", 1);
   var result = sqlQuery.ExecuteScalar<int>();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should use `conn.Table<inProgress>().FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Please see the answer below and let me know if it works for your use case. I added @ChetanRanpariya correct recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify you are getting only one row, you should use @Chetan's  code in the query.

In order to get the values without having to do a for loop you can use this:

```
using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
 {
     var row = conn.Table<inProgress>().Where(v => v.ID.Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault();
     isActive = row.Active;
     whatIsActive = row.whatIsActive;
     time = row.whatTime;
 }
```

For your second part, you would need to enforce the limit to one row. I'm assuming your table structure has the ID as a unique key so it should be good but I added a `LIMIT 1` in the query for safety. I used the sqlite-net library.

```
using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
{
   var sqlQuery = conn.Query("select Active, whatIsActive, time from inProgress where ID = ? LIMIT 1;", 1).FirstOrDefault();
   isActive = sqlQuery.Active;
   whatIsActive = sqlQuery.whatIsActive;
   time = sqlQuery.whatTime;
}
```

Comment: @mason I just used the code OP had posted as it was answering his original question of how to pull the values without a foreach loop, since he was already able to pull it the first way.

Comment: @mason Point taken. I updated my answer to reflect your comments and Chetan's line.

Comment: Awesome thanks All – that answered the first point (hence I marked this as the right answer). 
But for the second part, I’m getting an issue using “Query” I get the error “Argument 1:cannot convert from ‘string’ to ‘SQLite.TableMapping’